# Oracle group by issue with sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
PortfolioNumber LevelCode AccountNumber Status  track
123                2       A101          Failed  1
123                2       A102         Failed   1
123                2       A103         Passed   0

123                1       A101         Passed   0
123                1       A102         Passed   0
123                1       A103         Passed   0

123                3       A101        Failed    1
123                3       A102        Failed    1
123                3       A103        Failed    1

456                1       A406        Failed    1
456                1       A407        Passed    0  
456                1       A408        Failed    1
```

I have got this table by doing certain other join to other few tables,

What this table data denotes to -
Portflio Number (123) is there and we have in total three AccountNumber.
We have different LevelCode (here 1,2,3) and each level is tagged to portfolioNumber and will have same 3 accountnumber tagged too.
and We also have status at each row...Have created track Column jsut to have Failed as 1 and Passed as 0 which I tried using later in My below query (This column can be deleted)

What I am trying to find -

Lowest level code set per unique Portfolio Number(which Comprises of all three accountsNumber for that set ) where either of Status is failed

Query - Select PortfolioNumber, LevelCode,
min(LevelCode), sum(track) from
(table data which I got via some other tables join..pasted above)
group by PortfolioNumber, LevelCode
having sum(track) > 0'

But this does not give the correct result and all columns, running out of options now

Desired Result What I am

```
PortfolioNumber LevelCode AccountNumber Status  track
123                  2     A101           Failed  1
123                  2     A102           Failed  1
123                  2     A103           Passed  0

456                  1     A406           Failed  1
456                  1     A407           Passed  0 
456                  1     A408           Failed  1
```

Using Oracle

Comment: why you group by levelCode if you're looking for its min ?

Comment: Group by level code as I need all account from smallest level code per PortfolioNumber which have Failed status..hence kept min there..but not sure if this correct way to use

Comment: Is there a case that all 3 AccountNumbers do not exist for each LevelCode?

Comment: No that would not be the case

Comment: For PortfolioNumber = 456 why do you want all 3 rows in the results? LevelCode = 1 is the min which contains  Status = failed.

Comment: @forpas - My bad I updated data set and result set too , Requirement I have is to get small level code set (All 3 accountNumber) per PortfolioNumber which have either of  accountNumber failed..as shown in desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select distinct PortfolioNumber, 
       min(LevelCode) over (partition by PortfolioNumber) LevelCode
from tablename
group by PortfolioNumber, LevelCode
having sum(track) > 0
```

returns the PortfolioNumber/LevelCode combinations that you want.
Use it with the operator `IN` to get the rows of the table:

```
select * 
from tablename
where (PortfolioNumber, LevelCode) in (
  select distinct PortfolioNumber, 
         min(LevelCode) over (partition by PortfolioNumber) LevelCode
  from tablename
  group by PortfolioNumber, LevelCode
  having sum(track) > 0
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bcdef5cd2d4406320f0fc7f81ec8b113).
Results:

```
> PORTFOLIONUMBER | LEVELCODE | ACCOUNTNUMBER | STATUS | TRACK
> --------------: | --------: | :------------ | :----- | ----:
>             123 |         2 | A101          | Failed |     1
>             123 |         2 | A102          | Failed |     1
>             123 |         2 | A103          | Passed |     0
>             456 |         1 | A406          | Failed |     1
>             456 |         1 | A407          | Passed |     0
>             456 |         1 | A408          | Failed |     1
```

Comment: Wow, you were so quick and correct ...Thanks for helping appreciate did not know about this over (partition by PortfolioNumber)..Thanks again

Comment: @forpas-  Small issue with this which I missed to mention, incase for particular PortfolioNumber if all Level code are passed (that is sum(track) =0 ),with the above we wont be showing that Portfolio itself .. for this scenario I wanted to show the max (levelcode) for that portfolio..Sorry missed to mention earlier..tried updating in fiddle but not getting desired result..Please suggest

Comment: With assumption that always lower level code will be first all passed , then only after that higher level code accounts will be passed  per portfolio Number...means level1 all passed..level 2 some failed..then level 3 some failed

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0599f91fa5a517023f63d5e83d5cfe1

Comment: slct PortfolioNumber,
CASE 
 WHEN LevelCodeMax_Failed is null THEN LevelCodeMax_All_Passed 
 WHEN LevelCodeMax_All_Passed is null THEN LevelCodeMax_Failed 
 WHEN LevelCodeMax_Failed > LevelCodeMax_All_Passed THEN LevelCodeMax_Failed 
END as levelcode 
from(
select distinct PortfolioNumber as PortfolioNumber, 
   min(case when sum(track) > 0  then levelcode end) over (partition by PortfolioNumber)  LevelCodeMax_Failed,
   max(case when sum(track) = 0  then levelcode end) over (partition by PortfolioNumber)  LevelCodeMax_All_Passed
from tablename
group by PortfolioNumber, LevelCode
)

Comment: I was close to it above query I pasted ..but u query works well ..concise and clear..You are awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.levelcode = (select min(t2.levelcode)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.portfolionumber = t.portfolionumber and
                           t2.status = 'Failed'
                    );
```

This seems like the simplest solution and can be easily optimized with an index on `(portfolionumber, status, levelcode)`.

If you prefer, a similar method using window functions is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when status = 'failed' then levelcode end) over (partition by portfolionumber) as min_failed_levelcode
      from t
     ) t
where levelcode = min_failed_levelcode
```